# How to use transistions with css postions

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a sticky navbar with CSS and javascript. if the user scroll position is 200 or greater I'm changing the navbar position to fixed. but when we scroll the position does change but it's like a sudden change.

how can I smooth it?

Here is my code

```js
const App = (function() {

  function loadEventListeners() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', showStickyNav)
  }

  function showStickyNav() {
    const navbar = document.querySelector('#main-nav')
    window.scrollY >= 200 ? navbar.classList.add('sticky') : navbar.classList.remove('sticky')
  }

return {
  init() {
    loadEventListeners()
  }
}

})()
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}


#main-nav {
  background: #181d2f;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <div class="menu-center">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Listings</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Products <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Be A Vendor</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't whats your use case but I kind of feel you are looking for using the `sticky` position property of the Navbar since you want it to be `relative` till it overflows and then become `fixed`

Its so easy, you just need to use `position: sticky;` and `top` property in the navbar element. More about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

EDIT: By the way, maybe someone think I'm not helping you but I'm trying to make you think if your approach was the correct one or maybe you just wanted to do something that it's already built-in. Kind of thinking out the box instead of giving "do this and that", "copy paste this", etc. answers. :)

Comment: Hi, the reason I didn't use `position: sticky;` because the navbar disappears after we scroll a bit more. I have added the code in question.

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example using the built in snippet in stack overflow?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I have updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using javascript to apply the fixed position, you can jazz it up a bit too, with some animatable properites (list can be found via mozilla here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)
Add a class and adjust the height or font-size once it becomes sticky using css transitions.
That being said, using the sticky property in place of js gets some good results.